# How can I see how many times a username has appeared without counting manually

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, counting, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I've exported a list of customers, I need to find out the average subscription rate of each one. I have a list of about 2,000 transactions in alphabetical order. How can I find out how many times they appeared without counting manually?

Each transaction has a username, so I assume that there is some code that can take all the usernames and in the column next to them assign a number of how many times they have appeared on the sheet (This would tell me how many months they have paid)

This is an example:

```
Albert  | PAID
John    | PAID
John    | PAID
John    | PAID
John    | PAID
Tristan | PAID
Tristan | PAID
```

What I need help with is to get this result:

```
Albert: 1
John: 4
Tristan: 2
```

manually counting would cost too much precious time :)

Thank you very much for tackling this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=QUERY(A:A, 
 "select A,count(A) 
  where A is not null 
  group by A 
  label count(A)''", 0)
```

[image]

---

```
=QUERY(A:B, 
 "select A,count(A) 
  where B = 'PAID' 
  group by A 
  label count(A)''", 0)
```

[image: 0]